# Using arraylist<string> for setting adapter for autocomplete textview in android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, autocompletetextview

In my android app, I have an arraylist  containing server data received from server. I need to use this arraylist in the arrayadapter for using it in an autocomplete textview for showing suggestions while the user types the characters. I have seen many tutorials using string array in the arrayadapter and setting it for auto complete textview. But haven't found any solution using arraylist. Please help me out..

EDIT:

this is the code which I have used:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
    actv1=(AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    actv2=(AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);
    loc=new ArrayList<String>();
    SplashScreen ss = new SplashScreen();
    loc=ss.loc;


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,loc);
```

Adding loc is showing me an error in logcat as shown here: The constructor ArrayAdapter(CommunityFragment, int, ArrayList) is undefined

Comment: Show the code you tried to complete it that didn't work. What is causing issues?

Comment: change `ArrayAdapter<String>` to `ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: @mmlooloo. It is showing an error in eclipse like this: The constructor ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>>(CommunityFragment, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Comment: @Tee Jay remove my suggestion and use your old

Comment: @Tee Jay i made mistake, if you use just the below answer you will get result. sorry !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [ArrayAdapter documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29),

```
public ArrayAdapter (**Context context**, int resource, List<T> objects)
```

From your error, it looks like you're passing in a Fragment reference, which is not a context.

Try

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,loc);
```

Comment: Not working. Showing an error in eclise like this. The constructor ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>>(FragmentActivity, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Comment: I think it is not a problem with the context. I need to add an arraylist instead of array to the arrayadapter in my code..

Comment: @Tee Jay remove my suggestion and use your old

Comment: @TeeJay it is. `this` is not a valid context. Fragment does not extend Context Activity does and you need `getActivity()`

Comment: @Tee Jay i made mistake, if you use just the above answer you will get result. sorry !!